# Pulley braking question for dummies

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

I have a real dumb question. If you have a drum or a pulley that's moving a weight on a wire up and down with constant velocity, then it needs to be stopped within a certain time. What is the deceleration caused by braking?

My understanding is that when **lifting**, gravity counteracts the lifting force. So if you'd stop spooling the wire, the stopping time would be:

vf = v0 - g*t = 0 <=> t = v0/g

If that's not enough, you need a torque to stop it faster, causing a decelerative force. However, since the gravity assists in braking, this will be lower than when lowering the weight.

In **lifting** that would be a = v0/t - g

In **lowering** braking torque has to counteract gravity leading to: a = (v0+gt)/t

My question is, is this correct or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's

- first write the equations of motion, paying attention to the constraint of the wire (working only in traction and not in compression);
- then, let's assume the wire is working in traction, solve the problem to find the relation between rotation and the torque we need at the pulley, prescribing the desired motion (and thus, solving the inverse problem: we know the desired motion, we need to evaluate actions to have it), and check the wire condition "a posteriori"
- eventually, I'll evaluate the condition with no torque

### Equations of motion

The governing equations of the problem in the most general case are

$$\begin{aligned}
& I \ddot{\theta} = C - R \, T \\
& m \ddot{z} = T - m  g \\
& \text{constraint: either} \quad z = R \, \theta \quad \text{or} \quad T = 0 \ .
\end{aligned}$$

Assuming the wire is working (so $T > 0$), the kinematic constraint $z = R \, \theta$ holds and thus the problem has 1 degree of freedom.

### Solution of the 1-dof problem - wire working properly

Using the kinematic constraint, and taking $\theta$ as the independent dof, it's easy to find the relation between $\theta$ and $C$

$$\left( I + m R^2 \right) \ddot{\theta} = - m g R + C \ ,$$

and the tension in the wire (we'll check later that it needs to be positive, finding "limit conditions") is

$$T = m = \left( \ddot{z} + g \right) = m \left(R \ddot{\theta} + g \right) \ .$$

**Prescribed motion.** If we need a uniform accelerating motion
$$\theta(t) = \theta_0 + \Omega_0 t + \frac{1}{2} \alpha_0 t^2 \ ,$$

the torque at the pulley and the tension of the wire are

$$\begin{aligned}
 C & = m g R + \left(I + m R^2 \right) \alpha_0 \\
 T & = m \left( R \alpha_0 + g \right) \ .
\end{aligned}$$

**Limiting case.** The condition $T > 0$ implies a maximum value of deceleration (minimum value of acceleration)
$$ \alpha_0 \ge \overline{\alpha}_0 = -\frac{g}{R} \ .$$

We need to pay attention to this constraint only when we're raising the weight and we need to stop it "very fast", while we could avoid to worry about it when we want to stop a pulley that is bringing down a weight. This limiting condition corresponds to torque and tension
$$\begin{aligned} \overline{C} & = -\frac{g \, I}{R} \\ \overline{T} & = 0 \end{aligned}$$

**Free deceleration of a weight pulled upwards.** If you desire to evaluate the free deceleration, you just need to set $C=0$ in the equation of motion, to find

$$\alpha^{free} = \ddot{\theta}^{free} = - \frac{mgR}{I + mR^2} = - \dfrac{g}{R} \dfrac{mR}{\frac{I}{R} + m R} \qquad (> \overline{\alpha} \quad \text{ and thus always feasible with wire in tension}) \ .$$

Once the deceleration to zero is complete, you need to clamp the pulley otherwise the weight would fall down.